# HDMI Input and Recoding on Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook, hdmi

How can I get HDMI input into my 2011 Macbook Pro (Firewire, Thunderbolt, or USB seem to be the options)?

The end goal is to record iPad **output** somehow, and I can produce HDMI or VGA from the iPad.

**Related for Windows:** [Is it possible to record TV via HDMI?](https://superuser.com/questions/255285)

Comment: http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/models/ is expensive and not out yet, it seems

Comment: Not HDMI but interesting: http://www.amazon.com/Elgato-Video-Capture-Device-10020840/dp/B0029U2YSA/ref=acc_glance_e_ai_ps_t_4

Comment: or this thing http://www.amazon.com/Geniatech-iGrabber-Grabber-Button-Recording/dp/B002LRMOPO/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1325465971&sr=1-1 again composite not HDMI

Comment: Non-HDMI is such low resolution it's terrible.

Answer (score 1):

### HDMI to DisplayPort

Not feasible as far as I know. Pay no attention.

<del>Grab yourself a HDMI to DisplayPort adapter since your shiny MBP has displayport. Or does the MBP use Mini Displayport? Oh well, the principle remains the same.</del>

### VGA to USB

Epiphan makes a VGA to USB device conveniently named [VGA2USB](http://www.epiphan.com/products/frame-grabbers/vga2usb/) for a shocking $300USD:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Are you suggesting that I record TO my display port? The video source is external to the MBPro. Second solution is relevant, it turns out. $300? Wow.

Comment: @Yar I think you are correct that the first suggestion is not feasible. Not sure what I was thinking. And yes, $300 is *wow*. =/

Answer (score 0):

One way to record iPad video output (for those looking for another solution) is to mirror the iPad screen on the mac via Airplay, with apps like [Reflector](https://www.reflectorapp.com/) and [Airserver](http://www.airserverapp.com/) (both about $13), then record the screen via any number of screencast apps.

Note: requires iPad 2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

You cab use Blackmagic Design the Mini Recorder

https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/ultrastudiothunderbolt

It's the best and it works at once! I use it for live streaming and recording. Works with all known software even on Mac Windows and Linux (!!)

Have phun :P

Answer (score 0):

The best way to record your iPad's output (iPad screen):

1. connect your iPad to your Mac with the Lightning to USB Cable (the
   charger cable)
2. launch **Quicktime Player**
3. select File and "New Movie Recording"
4. **click the tiny arrow to the right of the red (record) button** and
   you'll see the iPad as a choice; after selecting it, your iPad's screen is previewed and you can start recording. Select the microphone to your iPad as well if you need audio from your iPad